# How to dowload and edit content of a website

Tags: theme-development, customization, themes

I am new to web design.

I know how to use themes with wordpress.

But I am interested in directly downloading the files from e.g. http://accesspressthemes.com/theme-demos/?theme=storevilla and edit the contents using wordpress. How can I edit the downloaded files directly using wordpress?

Answer (score 0):

The site you have linked to is a store for Wordpress themes, so you would need to pay for and then download the theme files that they give you.  You would then need to go to your own Wordpress install and install them there (instructions for installing a theme incase you haven't done this: http://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-install-a-wordpress-theme/).

Once your theme is installed, you will have the ability to customise it within Wordpress by going to Appearance > Customize on your dashboard left menu.  This will give you the options for customisation that are available with your theme.

If you have some knowledge of html then you can also customise your theme by going to Appearance > Editor and then choosing each of the files in the right menu to edit them directly.  I wouldn't recommend this option if you are new to Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly the files **right mouse click ->save as** but it not be usable since wordpress uses php and it run on server side and there is way to create wordpress theme not like that.
lets say that you :

**right mouse click ->save as**

- you will only get html/js/css code
- you will never get php code